# Make shell interpret operators enclosed in single-quotes

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, quoting, su

I have two commands built using the logical operator `&&`. The two commands are enclosed in single-quotes because they are to be passed as a command to root:

```
$ su -c 'sed -i '1i TEXT' file1.txt && sed -i '1i ANOTHER TEXT' file2.txt'
```

How do I make the shell to interpret the `&&` operator in the single-quotes but not interpret the rest of the characters in the single-quotes?

Comment: Did you really intend to use backticks there?

Comment: Thanks @muru for pointing out the typo, I intended single-quotes not backticks

Answer (score 3):

Just use single quotes (`'`), you've used backticks (`` ` ``):

```
$ su -c 'sed -i "1i TEXT" file1.txt && sed -i "1i ANOTHER TEXT" file2.txt'
```

Or double quotes:

```
$ su -c "sed -i '1i TEXT' file1.txt && sed -i '1i ANOTHER TEXT' file2.txt"
```

Comment: Don't know how I mistook backticks for single quotes, thanks for pointing out the mistake. As for your answer, testing with `echo a '&&' echo b` results in `a && echo b`, where as what I want is `a\nb` which is only displayed by `echo a && echo b`

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia test with `su -c 'echo a && echo b'`. You need to enclose the entire command in a single set of quotes: either ` su -c 'command1 && command1'` or `su -c "command1 && command2"`.

Comment: I tested `su -c 'echo a && echo b'` and can confirm it works. I thought single-quotes preserve the literal meaning of characters enclosed within it (which is why I was cautious running that command as root), so why does `su -c 'echo a && echo b'` not preserve the literal meaning of the characters `'echo a && echo b'`?

Comment: @MyWrathAcademia it does. What do you mean?

Comment: Actually, please don't do this in the comments. Ping me in [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) instead.